# Implement zoom effect in angular modal animation

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I have an angular modal which pops up as below:

[Angular modal popup](http://plnkr.co/edit/1epmosa7mqHiwF66oHEV?p=preview)

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open()">Launch demo modal</button>
```

But I need a zoom in out effect.

[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dtyohc28/6/)

Could you please help how to implement zoom effect t in an angular model?